# Grep data found in grep

Tags: unix, grep

I have a fairly simple grep that looks something like this:

```
grep -ri "logout.htm" -n -B 2
```

How can I grep the results of that and only display the 2 lines before if it contains "redirect.htm" before the logout.htm?

```
Results: 

Display this:
1.htm - 202ms
redirect.htm - 212ms
logout.htm - 250ms

Don't display this:

1.htm -- 201ms
userClickedLogoutController.htm - 255ms
logout.htm - 200ms
```

The criteria I want to match are logout.htm with redirect occurring within 2 lines before the logout.

Comment: Can you show the output contents and specifically what you want it to display?

Comment: I can't actually... I'm using this as an example because the work I do is HIPAA protected.   In essence I want to do a sub-grep in the -B 2 lines and display all 3 lines if I find the url "redirect.htm" in it.

Comment: Make up some data.

Comment: @glennjackman -- Mocked up some data for example sake

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not exclusively grep, but sed could do this:

```
sed "/Display this/,/Don't display this/!d" test.txt | sed '$d'
```